# PyCharm R plugin: how to clear the console?

Tags: r, pycharm

I am running an R file with the PyCharm R plugin. Is there a way to clear the console? I have tried `ctrl + L` and `cmd + L`, but neither of them works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a default key-binding for clearing the R-console in PyCharm, but you can press Ctrl-Shift-A (or navigate to Help-> Find action) to find the action, and set your own binding, in this case you would want to search for/bind clear all (not clear).

Comment: Thanks, but there is no action for "clear all", only for "clear".

Comment: Clear all only appears once you have something in the console, so try entering something into the R-console e.g. 1+1, then search for clear all and it should appear.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put the mouse cursor on the area of the R-console where the text is that you want to clear.
2. Press the right mouse button. Choose the option "Clear All".

See screenshot.

[image]